# Creating trigger in google script to save file to drive

Tags: google-apps-script, mapbox, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to modify this [script](https://github.com/mapbox/geo-googledocs) so that once a day it runs exporting the result to my drive and overwriting the file that is there. I'm completely new to google scripts so this might be a very basic request.   To clarify, i know how to set a tim trigger. I'm looking for how i edit the script so that it writes then overwrites the file to my drive on the timetrigger

Comment: What is your question? Do you want to know how to create a time-drive trigger or do you want to know how to export the result or how to overwrite a file or ...?

Comment: @Rubén thanks for looking, i've added a clarification to the question